# What is default color gradient for background inside Android EditText?

Tags: android

I'm trying to reuse the same greyish gradient background inside the Android EditText?  I want to use it as the background of color of a TextView?  How do I specify this gradient for my TextView?  I am not interested in Gradient for the Text itself just the background that it is written into like on an EditText?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This information is typically inside the specific Theme for your device. See the [themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) page on the Android website for more information about how to read and use them. Depending on your device, you could have a variety of different active themes so you will need to locate the source for the Theme you are looking for to acquire the exact gradient.